# Set document in firebase subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add document to firebase subcollection.

I want to have it like this: **jobs/email/randomid/[title,prof,etc]** saved here...

My code what I have tried:

```
setDoc(doc(db, "jobs", logUser.email, "randomid"), {
      title: enteredTitle,
      prof: enteredProf,
      pay: enteredPay,
      desc: enteredDesc,
    });
```

I was able to set document to main collection only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create documents, not collections.

The `jobs/email/randomid/` path is the path of a Collection (since it has 3 elements). So if you pass this path to the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#doc) method it will create a `DocumentReference` for a document in the `randomId` sub-collection with an auto-generated ID (i.e. the path of the document will be like `jobs/email/randomid/anotherrandomid`).

If you want the `randomId` value to be auto generated by Firestore you could do as follows:

```
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const randomId = doc(collection(db, '_')).id; // We use a fake collection named _

setDoc(doc(db, "jobs", logUser.email, randomId), {
      title: enteredTitle,
      prof: enteredProf,
      pay: enteredPay,
      desc: enteredDesc,
    });
```

HOWEVER, it means that if you want to query this `jobs/email/randomid/` subcollection you'll need to save/keep the value of `randomId` somewhere.

I strongly suggest to have fixed collection names/ids like, for example: `jobs/[useremail]/jobslist/[auto-generated-ID]`